# How to do ssh to remote server from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh

Can anyone let me know how to connect remote server from Jenkins (server1).
That is, how to do ssh via command line and a job?

```
sudo ssh user@server2
```

Comment: What type of job you are using? Freestyle, pipeline? Why `sudo`?

Answer (score 2):

For freestyle jobs, you would use the [Jenkins SSH plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh/).

[image: https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/42470275/ssh-global-cfg.png?version=1&modificationDate=1267072997000&api=v2]

[image: https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/42470275/ssh-job-cfg.png?version=1&modificationDate=1267072997000&api=v2]

For pipelines, you have [pipeline SSH steps](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin#pipeline-steps) which does the same:

```
node {
  def remote = [:]
  remote.name = 'test'
  remote.host = 'test.domain.com'
  remote.user = 'root'
  remote.password = 'password'
  remote.allowAnyHosts = true
  stage('Remote SSH') {
    sshCommand remote: remote, command: "ls -lrt"
    sshCommand remote: remote, command: "for i in {1..5}; do echo -n \"Loop \$i \"; date ; sleep 1; done"
  }
}
```